# Where should we install SSIS feature? on Data warehouse server or source DB Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse

We need to install SSIS on one server to use it for ETL.

We have two SQL Servers, one will be source data and the second one will be destination data.

Where should we install SSIS? on source DB server or destination DB server?

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is based on your current IT infrastructure.

Better practice are three environments: Developer, User Acceptance(UAT) and Production. Production environment is usually on a separate server.

For SSIS, each of these environment has its own data-sources and destination. Developers usually develops SSIS packages on Dev environment and after necessary testing, those are [DEPLOYED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages?view=sql-server-ver15) to UAT/ Prod SQL server catalog DB's. You can also deploy as file.

These packages can be scheduled to run on specific times, and usually it will be on out-of-office hours (night time) or off-peak hours. This will help with performance.

Still it depends on your server resources and data complexities.

Comment: Great, this is for setup environments, but where should I install the SSIS feature? on source or destination server?

Comment: There are 3 options: 1) Install on Source 2) Install on Destination 3) Install on independent server which is different from source and destination. In case of option-3, your licensing cost will increase as it totally different server.